# Visual Studio Debugging Is Slow

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

When I start up our rather large silverlight application it takes ages to start. This is because it compiles everything again every time I start up.

It does this even if it is just compiled everything.

The project is using RIA services as well which I realise contributes to this.

Is there any way to make startup faster?

Comment: get a faster box.... lol

Comment: You can optionally select not to build some dependencies in Visual Studio. Is that possible for your scenario?

Comment: The funny thing is that my box is pretty fast. SSD, 6 core, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing has changed, then I often use "attach to process" to hook into the silverlight app to debug it.

Comment: I like this idea, fast. But what do you attach to? I attached to IISExpress, and also directly to the iexplorer process. Neither worked. With IIS (not express) I remember having to attaching to a process called w3wp.exe

Comment: You have to select the code type to debug to be "Silverlight" which is incompatible with other debug types.  Then the process you attach to will be one of the iexplore.exe (or whatever browser) but in the types it will list (for me anyway) "Script, Silverlight, x86".

Comment: Nuts, it is soooooo fast. Thanks, that all worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

Another performance gain can be made by doing the following in Visual Studio:  Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | Turn on "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" option.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some of your source code were saved with a date or time in the future. Sometimes I change my computer date/time to debugging reasons, and save some files. When I restore to the correct date, the compiler compare these files with the output DLL's and recompile everything because they are newer than the DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

When my Silverlight debugging slowed to a death-crawl, I tried disabling the LastPass IE toolbar, and that fixed everything.  I went from taking 2 minutes to step over a line to almost instantaneous.  Maybe try disabling some IE addons?